# View.measuredHeight returns wrong value

Tags: android, animation, view

I needed to expand TextView from 0 to whatever height it had, but measuredHeight returns wrong value, with animation it crops a little space below, but with just "View.isVisible = true" it works fine.

P.S: It has problem on only large texts in one line.

Here is expand animation function:

```
private fun expand(view: View) {
    view.isVisible = true
    val widthMS = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(width, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST)
    val heightMS = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)
    view.measure(widthMS, heightMS)

    val heightAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, view.measuredHeight)
    heightAnimator.interpolator = AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator()
    heightAnimator.addUpdateListener { valueAnimator ->
        val value = valueAnimator.animatedValue as Int
        val layoutParams: ViewGroup.LayoutParams = view.layoutParams
        layoutParams.height = value
        view.layoutParams = layoutParams
    }

    heightAnimator.start()
}
```

Comment: Can you try with view.measure(0, 0)

Comment: @KishanMaurya Already tried, it's worse !

Comment: Can you give more context when you are trying to animate?

Comment: It's just part of custom view, to be more specific, I animate textview on some button click, nothing special.

Comment: val heightAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, view.height)

instead of view.measuredHeight, you have to use view.height

Answer (score 0):

This will work. Instead of `view.measuredHeight`, you have to use `view.height`

```
private fun expand(view: View) {
        view.isVisible = true
        val widthMS = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(width, View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST)
        val heightMS = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)
        view.measure(widthMS, heightMS)

        val heightAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, view.height)
        heightAnimator.interpolator = AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator()
        heightAnimator.addUpdateListener { valueAnimator ->
            val value = valueAnimator.animatedValue as Int
            val layoutParams: ViewGroup.LayoutParams = view.layoutParams
            layoutParams.height = value
            view.layoutParams = layoutParams
        }

        heightAnimator.start()
    }
```

Comment: No, it will give 0 value because view is not drawn yet :)

Comment: When you said that you are animation text view on button click, I thought, text view is already visible and you are just animating from 0 to its height.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Turns out the value of width was not accounting for margins. Thats how I fixed it

```
val layoutParams = view.layoutParams as ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams
val marginStart = layoutParams.marginStart
val marginEnd = layoutParams.marginEnd
val width = parent.width - marginStart - marginEnd
val widthSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(width, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY)
```

After supplying the correct `widthMS`, `view.measure(widthMS, heightMS)` returns correct value for height